# Generating C# classes from dataverse

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dataverse

Is there a way to generate C# classes from a dataverse endpoint?

Alternatively, is there a way to generate dataverse custom tables according to c# classes?

I'm searching for a "db(dataverse)-first" or, alternatively, a "code-first" solution to automate this process.

According to my research, this doesn't exist yet for .NET Core, as dataverse is a bit new, but I believe it would be greatly appreciated by the .NET community. If you know something about this development, even if it's still on its earlier stages, please let me/us know.

Comment: something of [such kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/org-service/generate-early-bound-classes) ?

Comment: Yes Mong Zhu, exactly, but I forgot to specify I'm searching for something that will work on .NET Core, I'll update my question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LuisGouveia not sure why you would have a problem using these for .net core even if the tool doesn't run on it to generate them, it just outputs plain old c# objects

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a year too late, but I am also looking for a solution to connect EF6 Core and Microsoft Dataverse, but according to Microsoft is still a nice to have approach. (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/plan)

> ***DataVerse (formerly Common Data Services)***
>
> Status: In-progress
>
> T-shirt size: Ongoing
>
> DataVerse is a column-based data store designed for rapid development
> of business applications. It automatically handles complex data types
> like binary objects (BLOBs) and has built-in entities and
> relationships like organizations and contacts. An SDK exists but
> developers may benefit from having an EF Core provider to use advanced
> LINQ queries, take advantage of unit of work and have a consistent
> data access API. The team will consider different ways to improve the
> .NET developer experience connecting to DataVerse.